# Apache Beam Session Windowing and joining across PCollections

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

we have two Streams S1 and S2 of events that have the same keys (userId). Is it possible to apply a session Window across both collections so that an occurrence of Key X in either stream would contribute to the session? Would this create Windows across PCollections that would let us join these afterwards?

For Context:

- We are using the DataFlowRunner
- both S1 and S2 are unbounded collections from PubSubIO

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct - you can do this because windows come into play when you perform grouping operations. This means that you can do something simple like this:

```py
p = beam.Pipeline(...)

# Assume that timestamp information is already in the streams
first_stream = p | ReadMyFirstStream() | beam.WindowInto(window.Sessions(...))
second_stream = p | ReadMySecondStream() | beam.WindowInto(window.Sessions(...))

joined_streams = (
    {'first': first_stream,
     'second': second_stream}
    | beam.CoGroupByKey())
```

The joined streams PCollection will generate windows where elements from both streams are grouped together.

---

This will work in Java as well. I answered using Python for the sake of simplicity. Let me know if you'd prefer Java code.

Comment: Thanks Pablo. How does this work exactly? Do the two session objects have to be the same instance or is the same  configuration sufficient? How does beam retain the state between collections? And how do those windows align? What we are trying to do is creating sessions where elements in S1 are in the same session as S2, assuming they are no more than `gapDuration` apart. Many thanks again!

Comment: Right, so - this is a non-intuitive feature of Beam, but windowing PTransforms only 'mark' an element's window, but they take effect when they reach a grouping operation (Stateful DoFn, GroupByKey, CoGroupByKey). When you pass your two PCollections into CoGroupByKey, they are grouped by key+window - so in fact the windowing has to be the same for them to be grouped

Comment: Thanks again. So, that means we can group them if Sessions are the same. But does the session take effect on both inputs as well? For example, if we have a gapDuration of 30m and items are emitted on Streams S1 and S2 as follows: `S1: s1_1@1m s1_2@60m s1_3@65m`, `S2: s2_1@19m s2_2@65m`, would we get sessions of (s1_1, s2_1), (s1_2, s2_2, s1_3) or would we just get sessions (s1_1), (s2_1), (s1_2, s1_3), s(2_2)? I hope this makes sense :)

Comment: Right, the session takes effect on both inputs (sessions would be (s1_1, s2_1), (s1_2, s2_2, s1_3) )